# AppWarp Unity SDK: BAD_REQUEST when sending bytes array to peers

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, appwarp

I'm running into the issue when trying to call *WarpClient.GetInstance().SendUpdatePeers(someBytesArray)*. Have to mention that *WarpClient.GetInstance().SendChat(msg)*, which is called just before the update peers, works perfect, and ll the user in the room gets the message.
The bytes size array is of size ~400 KB, so the immediate suspect is that it's just too large. Found no information about data size restriction though.
Android player is build, if this matters.
Any ideas?
10x

Answer (score 0):

Please see the API reference

http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/java-api-reference/#sendupdatepeers

The request is failing because of the size.

Comment: Hi dhruv, thanks for the answer, it clarifies. Please note that Unity API docs (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcbNk23T_5Y) do not mention that restriction.
Anyway,how one can send more then 1K of data? Kind of storing it somewhere on your cloud and sending URI?

Comment: Well, the right link for the above comment is http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/unity3d-game-developers-home/unity3d-client-apis/#subscriberoom

Comment: Yes, storing large amounts of data is better on [App42 backend](http://api.shephertz.com/app42-dev.php). It allows you to store JSON as well as files depending on your requirements. AppWarp is suitable for real-time message exchange in game rooms.

Comment: Yes, you simply need to add both the assets.